# MKDIR php command does not create the folder

Tags: php, linux, centos, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder for my user once they registered, however even though there is no error with the syntax it still does not want to create the folder. Do I need to edit any of my server php configurations?

```
$dirpath = "/users/".$username;
mkdir($dirpath);
```

Comment: try `mkdir( $dirpath, 0755, true );`

Comment: Also check permissions

Comment: how would i check the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
$dirpath = "/users/".$username;
mkdir($dirpath, 0700);
?>
```

The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access. For more information on modes, read the details on the chmod() page.

If you're working on Windows OS mode is ignored.

Comment: @HubertKaluzny try using mkdir($dirpath, 0777); and check the permisssions of the dir /users

Comment: the permissions of everything in my server directory is 777

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the directory "/users" is writable for whatever user your webserver is running as.

Comment: the users directory is writatable in its got permissions 777

Comment: Is $username set to something other than an empty string?

Comment: no, everything that includes that is ok, im getting the mysqli queries

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I have a query that inserts the user into the table and it works therefore it can not be that